# Trying to add a custom field to the Magento page CMS

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

I am attempting to add a custom field to the Magento CMS page editor using [this](https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/) guide, but I am not able to get the additional field to display in the backend.

Here are the files I have created:

**ddog_customcms.xml in /app/etc/modules**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ddog_customcms>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends/>
        </ddog_customcms>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml in /app/code/local/ddog/customcms/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ddog_customcms>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </ddog_customcms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ddog_customcms>
                <class>ddog_customcms_Model</class>
            </ddog_customcms>
        </models>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
                <observers>
                    <ddog_customcms_page_edit_tab_content>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>ddog_customcms_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cmsField</method>
                    </ddog_customcms_page_edit_tab_content>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
        </events>
        <resources>
            <ddog_customcms_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>ddog_customcms</module>
                </setup>
            </ddog_customcms_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**content_custom column added to cms_page database table**

**observer.php in /app/code/local/ddog/customcms/Model/**

```
<?php

class ddog_customcms_observer
{
    public function addNewCmsField($observer)
    {
        //get CMS model with data
        $model = Mage::registry('cms_page');
        //get form instance
        $form = $observer->getForm();
        //create new custom fieldset 'ddog_customcms_content_fieldset'
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('ddog_customcms_content_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Custom'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));
        //add new field
        $fieldset->addField('content_custom', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'content_custom',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content Custom'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content Custom'),
            'disabled'  => false,
            //set field value
            'value'     => $model->getContentCustom()
        ));

    }
}
```

I have cleared the cache but I can't get the field to appear anywhere in the page editor. Can anybody help?

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53094

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have already taken a look at that answer and attempted the steps, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

here in declaration

```
<events>
     <adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
         <observers>
             <ddog_customcms_page_edit_tab_content>
                 <type>singleton</type>
                 <class>ddog_customcms_Model_Observer</class>
                 <method>cmsField</method>
             </ddog_customcms_page_edit_tab_content>
         </observers>
     </adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
</events>
```

you set method name `cmsField` but in observer you write method name `addNewCmsField` change it to `cmsField` and it will work

Comment: Good spot! I've amended the method name to cmsField, but I still can't see any new fields when editing a page. Is there anything I need to do other than clearing the cache to get it show?

Comment: There is no any error in code I have try your code and its working just change the class name of observer to Ddog_Customcms_Model_Observer

Comment: Ok I have made that change, my observer now has the class name ddog_customcms_Model_Observer. I'm still not seeing the field though :(

Comment: Did you check the log? is there any error because In my admin page I can see one field

Comment: Field display in "Content" tab.

Comment: The only error in the log is this "2017-07-07T13:23:16+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/page/html/scripts/before_body_end.phtml" but I suspect that's not related to this issue.

Comment: Write a log in observer and check

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Magento. Please could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Thanks. Added to observer.php and cleared the cache, but no observer.log in /var/log